# jquery hide/show divs troubleshooting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a series of links to hide/show six different divs.  I want the page to load where all of the six divs are hidden.  Upon clicking on one of the six links, the respective div should fade in.  When clicking on any of the other links, the current should fade out, and the newly selected div should appear.

Here is the start of the jQuery script that I placed just inside the opening body tag:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $("#1").on('click', function() {
   $(this).fadeOut();
   $("#Graphics, #Jury, #Witness, #Mock, #Continuing").fadeOut();
   $("#Strategy").fadeIn();
});
    </script>
```

Here are the links:

```
<a href="#Strategy" id="1">Strategy &amp; Theme Development</a>
    <a href="#Graphics" id="2">Graphics</a>
    <a href="#Jury" id="3">Jury Selection</a>
    <a href="#Witness" id="4">Witness Preparation</a>
    <a href="#Mock" id="5">Mock Trials &amp; Focus Groups</a>
    <a href="#Continuing" id="6">Continuing Legal Education</a>
```

These are the target divs:

```
<div id="Strategy"></div>
<div id="Graphics"></div>
<div id="Jury"></div>
<div id="Witness"></div>
<div id="Mock"></div>
<div id="Continuing"></div>
```

I'm not sure if the links to the divs override the jQuery effect or not.

Comment: Why are you fading out the div's if they are initially hidden?

Comment: My goal is to fade them out after clicking on a second link.  Currently I don't have the divs hidden, just trying to work out the kinks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").on('click', function (e) {
        var currentElement = $(e.currentTarget);
        var divToShow = currentElement.attr('href'); // grab the id of the div we need to show
        // now find an visible divs
        var visibleDiv = $('div').filter(function() { return $(this).is(':visible'); });

        if (visibleDiv.length) // if there is a div already visible, fade it out then fade in the target div
        {
            $(visibleDiv).fadeOut(400, function() {
                $(divToShow).fadeIn();
            });
        }
        else $(divToShow).fadeIn(); // fade it in.
    });
});
```

You already have the ids of the `div`s that you want to fade linked to the `a` tags via their `href` attributes.

I'd just add a common class to the `a` tags that control the fading `divs`, and then when any of those are clicked, grab its `href` attribute and fade in that div, while fading out the currently visible div (if one exists).

I'd also add a common class to the fade-able `div`s so you can filter through them without touching the rest of the DOM.

[**JSFiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ovgss5nc/1/)

UPDATE:

Here's an example of giving common classes to your elements:

For the `a` tags, add a class of `hideShow` to all of them:

```
<a href="#Strategy" id="1" class="hideShow">Strategy &amp; Theme Development</a>
<a href="#Graphics" id="2" class="hideShow">Graphics</a>
<a href="#Jury" id="3" class="hideShow">Jury Selection</a>
etc...
```

For the 'div' tags, add a class of `hideable` to all of them:

```
<div id="Strategy" class="hideable">The strategy div</div>
<div id="Graphics" class="hideable">The Graphics div</div>
<div id="Jury" class="hideable">The Jury div</div>
etc...
```

Then in the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".hideShow").on('click', function (e) {
        // you clicked one of the `.hideShow` a tags!
        ....
        // now filter through all the divs with `class="hideable"` to find a visible one
        var visibleDiv = $('.hideable').filter(function() { return $(this).is(':visible'); });
    });
});
```

Comment: Regarding assigning common classes, can you please give me an example?  Not being too skilled in scripting, I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how that will work.

Comment: @JoeO'Toole See the update in my post.  Hope that helps.

Comment: This worked perfectly!  Follow up question: How do I hide all these divs initially on page load?

Comment: You mean the `hideable` divs? In the CSS: `.hideable { display: none }`

Answer (score 0):

You should select IDs of elements, not href values of elements.

```
$("#1").on('click', function() {
$(this).fadeOut();
$("#2, #3, #4, #5, #6").fadeOut();
$("#1").fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: no, those are the link ids (#1-#6), the div ids I'm trying to show/hide are #Strategy, #Graphics, etc.

Comment: You should include the code you have for the `div` elements as well to avoid confusion.

Comment: Okay, I've added the target divs.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try acting on them individually:

`$("#Graphics,#Jury,#Witness,#Mock,#Continuing").each(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut();
});`

You may also want to look at [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)